# Should I create a worker thread when extend a Service?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a service for playing music that extends *Service* class. It has local *MediaPlayer* instance and performs music playback without creating working thread. It looks like UI thread is not blocked, I can freely navigate through my app while listening to music. I am a bit confused because on documentation guide it is said that such operation blocks main thread. Could someone explain what`s going on? Should I create working thread inside my service?

> A service runs in the same process as the application in which it is
>   declared and in the main thread of that application, by default. So,
>   if your service performs intensive or blocking operations while the
>   user interacts with an activity from the same application, the service
>   will slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting application
>   performance, you should start a new thread inside the service.

The snippet looks like this

```
public class MusicPlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        playNext();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        startForeground(1, mNotification);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }

    public void onPlay() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

As we can see in official document of Android:

> Service This is the base class for all services. When you extend this
>   class, it's important that you create a new thread in which to do all
>   the service's work, because the service uses your application's main
>   thread, by default, which could slow the performance of any activity
>   your application is running.
>
> IntentService This is a subclass of
>   Service that uses a worker thread to handle all start requests, one at
>   a time. This is the best option if you don't require that your service
>   handle multiple requests simultaneously. All you need to do is
>   implement onHandleIntent(), which receives the intent for each start
>   request so you can do the background work. The following sections
>   describe how you can implement your service using either one for these
>   classes.

If you are doing heavy work in service it's possible to block ui and you should create a thread or use intent service for non-blocking ui.